# how to label changing postures?

Tags: meditation-posture, mahasi-sayadaw

Up until now when i change postures i said in my language the word for changing to a sitting posture and then "sitting" three times - now i think it overdoing it and i think maybe its best just to say "sitting sitting sitting" when changing posture form standing to sitting

and also the opposite instead of say "rising rising rising" and than "standing standing standing" i wonder if its best just to say "standing standing standing"

What is the offical accepted view on how one should lable the changing of postures in the mahasi sayadaw technique - specifically what ven.yuttdhammo is teaching ?

i wouldnt mind hearing opinions about this subject on whats best to do ect - but i would also like to know what is commonly recommended to most practitioners officially to do, what is the standard way of labeling the changing of postures -

also im asking on how to this in daily life and also when mediating or at a retreat -   if i dont have time to label 3 times "sitting sitting sitting"  but only 1 time "sitting" - whats the way to label in that case ?  (im asking what to label in on both scenarios)

Comment: "i wouldnt mind hearing opinions.." & "im asking on how to this in daily life.." which to choose?

Comment: i dont understand your question ?  when in a retreat you have time to label  3 times when you change posture and in daily life you usually have time to label once when changing posture

Comment: The labeling has many aims. Main aim is practices to live Now. another is understand the duality of body and mind.

Comment: yes im aware of why do it - im asking on how to do it - more specifically the labeling of the change of posture

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of using words to note is that you are labeling the thing you are meditating on in accordance with what it is. If you are rising up to stand, you aren't actually standing at that time, so it is inappropriate to note it with the word standing, as you want the noting to be simultaneous with the object itself.

Ajahn Yuttadhammo explains some of the principles of the labeling being simultaneous in his section on walking meditation on page 16 of his [meditation booklet](http://static.sirimangalo.org/howto/HTM.pdf) where he writes:

> One should make the mental note   at the exact moment of each
>   movement,  neither before or after the movement.
>
> If the mental note, "stepping right",  is made before the foot moves ,
>   one is noting  something that has not yet occurred. If  one  move s
>   the  foot first and then note s,  "stepping right", one is noting
>   something in the past. Either way,   this cannot   be   considered
>   meditation,   as   there   is   no awareness of reality in either case
>   .

Comment: yes i am aware of that - i want to know about what to label when changing postures

Comment: Label it whatever kind of motion you are doing. If you are getting up, note it as 'rising' or 'bending', for example.

Answer (score 0):

> if i dont have time to label 3 times "sitting sitting sitting" but
>   only 1 time "sitting" - whats the way to label in that case ? (im
>   asking what to label in on both scenarios)

According above statement you may have bypass the preliminary steps. That is the reason for asking "What to label"?

By practicing technique like walking meditation from beginners steps.(I think you know how to walk) you may understand what to label.

Comment: im asking what to label 3 times or 1 time ?

Comment: If you put left leg then label "Left", and when put right foot label it as "Right".

Comment: Or..Left.....Right.... Left,Left,left....Right,Right,Right.....

Comment: im asking about the labeling of the change of posture not about the walking-  to label 3 times or 1 time ?  i got different recommendation depending on whether its in a retreat or whether its in daily life

Comment: Whether its in a retreat or whether its in daily life there is main 4 postures, sitting, standing,walking,sleeping and change the posture. so when changing select appropriate label ( say turning) and label it throughout the changing. The number of time needs to repeat depend on the speed of the action.

Comment: If you can concentrate on the mental action than the physical body.